# Is there a way to declare a java method as infix for kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, dsl

Is there a way to declare a method from a java class so that it is callable as an `infix` function from kotlin, like this :

```
public class Foo {
  public void doFoo (String bar) {}
}
```

Then  from a kotlin file

```
foo doFoo "bar"
```

Comment: question is not a duplicate though

Comment: How so? It seems identical to me. If you outline the difference then I will happily re-open.

Comment: See @JoeClay  comment, I was not looking for a wrapper

Comment: The question is the same - using wrappers is just one (the only) way to accomplish it - so it *is* a duplicate. I have added a line to the answer that specifies there is no way to do this "natively" within the Java code.

Comment: It is not the same way, because you need to write a wrapper for every function, and you also need to copy paste java doc or write @see everytime... The original question has a title that look similar, but the OP in the thread is already using a wrapper, so the question should be "How to wrap a java function correctly in kotlin". The infix operator is merely related to the question

Comment: The infix operator is not "merely related". He is trying to accomplish exactly the same thing as you, except he's a bit closer to a solution. I've edited the question to make it even closer. It's in everyone's best interest that information is more focused and less disparate. Don't take it personally that I closed this.

Comment: I'm not taking anything personnally, I saw the question before publishing it, but it  was already too much opiniated and didn't give me a clue of what i was looking for, that is : it's just not possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As of Kotlin 1.3, no:](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#operators)

> Since Java has no way of marking methods for which it makes sense to use the operator syntax, Kotlin allows using any Java methods with the right name and signature as operator overloads and other conventions (`invoke()` etc.) **Calling Java methods using the infix call syntax is not allowed.**

Comment: Has the behaviour changed? The linked duplicate seems to suggest it is possible.

Comment: The duplicate (and zsmb13's answer) seem to show that it can be done by defining a wrapper on the Kotlin side of the fence, but there's no way to declare the method as infix purely through the Java code.

Comment: The bit you've bolded would contradict that. Calling Java methods using the infix call syntax **is** *allowed*, if you define a wrapper. Marking Java methods in Java code as infix is not possible (willing to accept this, but I don't see any reason why they couldn't use an annotation to accomplish the same thing)

Comment: A @infix annotation would be just fine... A shame they aren't doing it tho

Answer (score 3):

You can add an `infix` extension to get that syntax from Kotlin:

```
infix fun Foo.doFoo(bar: String) {
    return doFoo(bar)
}
```

Comment: This loooks an interesting way around, but it doesn't maintain the documentation though